# What is the current status of RDS 2.0?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation, standard

Radio data system is the standard used for embedding small digital information in FM radio. I am excited for the release of the new RDS 2.0 standard. But I am not really sure if the technical standard has been finalised. If it has been finalised, can you point me to the documentation of technical specifications of RDS 2.0?

Are there FM stations or FM radio equipment that support RDS 2.0? Or are there atleast plans or announcements about any FM stations or FM radio equipment supporting RDS 2.0?

Comment: I am not really sure if this question is relevent to this site or not. Inform me if it is off-topic. I'll delete it

Comment: To be clear, I am asking for the technical specifications of a communications standard, so I believe it is relevant here

Comment: There's been demonstrators for RDS2. You can download the current RDS standard for money from IEC. My two cents: a deader-at-birth technology has seldom been specified; both the infos one can get over broadcast aren't very sexy compared to what you can get via internet, which is pretty ubiquitous where there's FM reception these days, and analog FM radio is being abandoned in Europe, where RDS is most important. So, both the use cases slip, as well as the future-proofness of transmitters. I doubt many car stereo manufacturers will care to implement RDS2.GPS Navis,maybe,but even those->internet

Comment: Other than that, there's multiple open-source RDS (1) implementations, and since RDS2 is specified to be backwards-compatible, extending these to do RDS2 belongs in the realm of not-very-exciting engineering.

Comment: Does that mean currently there are no FM stations or FM radio equipment that support RDS 2.0? Or there atleast plans or announcements that an equipment or a channel will support RDS 2 in the future?

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I believed that RDS 2.0 could have a market in developing countries like India especially as it supports UTF-8 encoding. Whatever, let the best and the most viable technology survive.

Comment: India is **massively** rolling out DRM to reach rural areas, so no FM for these, and for urban areas, 2G/3G/4G doesn't seem so bad... as said, there's a couple of demonstrators, but no commercially available devices. I'm not aware of anyone actually planning to implement this, for the reasons given above.

Comment: Common sense dictates that this won't happen. Radio listening has been in steady decline world-wide, over the past 70 years or so. The TV has been invented. The internet has been invented. To occupy a wide, valuable frequency band for FM radio in the year 2018 is quite a waste, really.

Comment: @Lundin It's unlikely that RDS2 would occupy any new spectrum. It'd replace the RDS1 carrier that is already existing in FM broadcast radio.

Answer (score 1):

RDS2 is now official standard. For testing and commenting you can load the draft version from [RDS-Forum homepage](http://www.rds.org.uk/2010/RDS2Spec.htm) 
The new RDS2 includes also the RBDS and UECP standards.

Receiver are available so as [USB-Stick](http://www.rx014.com/home/buildpage.php) 
Encoders are available e.g. from [WorldCast systems](https://www.worldcastsystems.com/en/c22p107/rds-encoding/new-audemat-rds-encoder)  tested in Paris (Radio France) and in 14. May 2019 in Budapest (NMHH Workshop)
In addition to the familiar 11.4 37-bit and 21-bit groups, RDS2 offers you additional payload volumes of up to 34.2 groups per second with 7 bytes (56 bits) of payload.

This is 14 kByte / Minute and enough for little pictures/Logos, Internet addresses, ODA Data (Open Data Application). Together wit a possible LTE interface (e.g. Smartphone or Car Radio) you have the best of two worlds Analog and Digital. Some newer encoders could implement it with a simple software update, so it's not a question of price whether the transmitters switch or stay behind.

The available receiver chip is a standard NXP TEF6688 with modified firmware, this shows that the receiver market is also not hindered by high hurdles.